# JSON Structure for implementing nodes on Hypergraph in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Hello I am wondering how I can create a data structure using JSON that has the following parameters.

1. A name (These will be set by a file line by line which has a name on each line such as ("x1", "x2", "x3"...,"x100")
2. a null float (We will call this parameter A of the object)
3. a null float (We will call this parameter B of the object)
4. a null float (We will call this parameter C of the object)
5. math.random(); (This is the x-coordinate of the point)
6. math.random(); (This is the y-coordinate of the point)

So whenever a text file is read it should create about 200 of these objects.

To implement this I created 3 separate files

**main.java**

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainCode {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
      { 
          // We need to provide file path as the parameter: 
          // double backquote is to avoid compiler interpret words 
          // like \test as \t (ie. as a escape sequence) 
        jsonWrite myWriter = new jsonWrite();
        myWriter.genNode();
        jsonRead myReader = new jsonRead();
        myReader.readNode("x1");
      }
}
```

**jsonWrite.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.util.LinkedHashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray; 
import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 

public class jsonWrite 
{ 

    public JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(); 
    public JSONArray nArray = new JSONArray(); 
    public Map pointNode = new LinkedHashMap(); 

        public void genNode() throws FileNotFoundException{
                File file = new File("F:\\Java Workspaces\\Files\\myNodes.nodes.txt");   
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
                String s = new String();
                int index = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                    s = sc.nextLine();
                      if ( index > 6 ){
                        pointNode = new LinkedHashMap(6); 
                        pointNode.put("Name", s); 
                        pointNode.put("A", null);
                        pointNode.put("B", null);
                        pointNode.put("C", null);
                        pointNode.put("X", Math.random()); 
                        pointNode.put("Y", Math.random());  
                        nArray .add(pointNode ); 
                      }
                      index++;
                }

            jo.put(s, nArray ); 
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("JSONNode.json"); 
            pw.write(jo.toJSONString()); 

            pw.flush(); 
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("JSON Created!");
        }

}
```

**jsonRead.java**

```
// Java program to read JSON from a file 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map; 

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray; 
import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 
import org.json.simple.parser.*; 

public class jsonRead(String s); 
{ 

    public void readNode() throws IOException, ParseException{
        // parsing file "JSONFile.json" 
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("JSONFile.json")); 

        // typecasting obj to JSONObject 
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj; 

        // getting address 
        Map address = ((Map)jo.get(s)); 

        // iterating address Map 
        Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = address.entrySet().iterator(); 
        while (itr1.hasNext()) { 
            Map.Entry pair = itr1.next(); 
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue()); 
        } 

        // getting phoneNumbers 
        JSONArray myNodeArray = (JSONArray) jo.get(s); 

        // iterating phoneNumbers 
        Iterator itr2 = myNodeArray.iterator(); 

        while (itr2.hasNext())  
        { 
            itr1 = ((Map) itr2.next()).entrySet().iterator(); 
            while (itr1.hasNext()) { 
                Map.Entry pair = itr1.next(); 
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue()); 
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("JSON Opened!");
    }   

}
```

the hope is that future functions which will be written in the main will be able to access each of the 200 objects and set Parameter A, Parameter B, Parameter C, and plot the coordinate on a canvas using the randomly generated x-y coordinate of the object. However, I believe my implementation of the objects and the way they are read is incorrect.

Basically the implementation of what I am doing is a hypergraph. So once I understand how to create a nice data structure using JSON I will have to do the same to create a data structure for storing the nets. This will also be read in through a file and will tell which nodes connect to each other and whether they are just edges or hyper edges.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

So instead of trying to handle this with JSON I just took an easier approach and created classes in java one for Nodes and another for an ArrayList of Nodes. Then I created various setters and getters in both and made a function for adding a node. This function would add an object of type Node to the ArrayList Object. It worked brilliantly and was exactly what I wanted.